# How to save user input in database from django form

Tags: python, django

I hava created a small project in django where i have created a form and with 3 fields now i want if user type his name , email and invite message then it should save in databse.

i am unable to save the data in database.

**form.py**

```
from datetime import datetime
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DatePickerInput
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DateTimePickerInput
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import TimePickerInput

# from .models import check


class Email_app(forms.Form):
    Name = forms.CharField()
    Email = forms.EmailField()
    Invite = forms.CharField()
    start_date = forms.DateField(label="Start_Date", widget=DatePickerInput())
    start_time = forms.DateField(label="Start_Time", widget=TimePickerInput())
    end_date = forms.DateField(label="End_Date", widget=DatePickerInput())
    end_time = forms.DateField(label="End_Time", widget=TimePickerInput()) 
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

Form > [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEKcv.jpg)

below is the **view.py**

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import  formatdate
# from email import encoders
from email.encoders import encode_base64
import os,datetime
COMMASPACE = ', '
# from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from operators.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER
from . import forms
from django.core.mail import send_mail
# Create your views here.
#DataFlair #Send Email
def email_app(request):
    sub = forms.Email_app()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sub = forms.Email_app(request.POST)
        subject = 'Welcome to Email Event'
        message = 'Hope you are enjoying your Django'
        recepient = str(sub['Email'].value())
        invite = str(sub['Invite'].value())
        start_date = str(sub['start_date'].value())
        start_time = str(sub['start_time'].value())
        end_date = str(sub['end_date'].value())
        end_time = str(sub['end_time'].value())
        send_mail(subject, 
            message, EMAIL_HOST_USER, [recepient], fail_silently = False)
        print(start_date)
        print(end_date)
        send_mail1(recepient,invite)
        return render(request, 'Email_app/success.html', {'recepient': recepient})
    return render(request, 'Email_app/index.html', {'form':sub})
```

i am taking the input as well in view.py but i need help to save the same input from user in database.
Though it is easy to save from model.py but i am working on form.
So is there any way to save the inputs in database from form.py.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by now you should have figured a solution, but anyway...

In order to save into your database since you already have a `form.py` defined you just need to call `form.save()` in your view.

In your `views.py`

```py
def email_app(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = Email_app(request.POST)
       # Do Something
       form.save() #<-- saving the form to the database
       return render(request, 'Email_app/success.html', {'recepient': recepient})

    else:
      form = Email_app()
    return render(request, 'Email_app/success.html', {'recepient': recepient})
```

I'd recommend you name your forms like: `EmailForm()` in order to avoid any conflicts and unnecessary bugs in your code